# Error messages about missing Codebase attribute when loading webstart application

Tags: java, java-7, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a webstart application in which all the jars are signed (my own and third-party). When load it with Java7u25, I see error messages like the following in the Java console:

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://example.com/webstart/application-jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://example.com/webstart/application-jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
```

I read up on the changes in 7u25 here: http://blog.eisele.net/2013/06/java-se-7-update-25-release-notes.html

The note says to specify the Codebase attribute in the JAR's manifest at the time of building and have it match the Codebase in the JNLP file. How is this supposed to be setup to work for third-party jars like commons-beanutils which clearly don't have this manifest entry?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. I am working on figuring it out. PLEASE post an answer if you find one.

Comment: the answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275384/missing-codebase-manifest-attribute-forxxx-jar) seems to be in the same ballpark, but as you can see by my comment to the answer, his solution did not work for me, as I got an error. #StillLookin #Ugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are signing the jar files yourself (third party as well as your own) you can just add the necessary parameters to the third party jars manifest.mf (open them with an archive utility, i.e. archive manager on ubuntu or try 7-zip etc for windows) add the parameters as you have to your own jars manifest (re package them, on ubuntu this happens automatically when you close the file after editing, I'm not sure if you're on windows) and then build your application/sign all the jars.

This worked for me although I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Is it ok to open a third-party jar and add to it's manifest? That is my concern that for Codebase to work, I will need to update all jars (mine + third-party) at deployment time which is inefficient and error-prone IMO.

Comment: Well it depends on the third party jars licence I guess. I doubt anyone would object to adding attributes to the manifest. Regarding the efficiency of it, it is time consuming but you only need to do it once, for each jar.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the way to do it, we have to add the manifest entries even for third-party jars.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot sign yourself see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21134770/1061519) for a way to add an exception for the site of the app.