# Security policy on Applets

Tags: java, security, applet

I want to code an applet wich needs a special security permissions, ie: network access to do an http GET to a site.

I signed the applet myself and did a simple test with this result:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "www.google.com:80" "connect,resolve")

I also try to add the security policy inside the manifest file with no luck.

I dont really understand what should be the correct producedure,

- Should i use a policy file inside the jar? where exactly it should be located?
- Should i put some policy definition on the APPLET tag on the HTML?
- Should i do something inside the code to ask for privileges/permission?
- Should i use other launch method like JNLP? does this make any difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior depends on java Version. Starting from java 7u51 both jws and applet need to be signed with a valid certificate (not self signed). http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html#newft
There are only two security levels sandbox and all-permissions. The attribute permissions must be specified in the manifest and in the jnlp file. To perform http request sandbox is enough. Read this article http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: Thanks. What have worked for me is implementing PrivilegedAction on my classes and doing the AccessController.doPrivileged().

Comment: "sandboxed" permission is generally insufficient to violate Same Origin Policy. A limited form of crossdomain.xml is supported, but I don't think that can do anything useful with google.com's policy.

Answer (score 0):

I answer similar question here: [Warning on Permissions attribute when running an applet with JRE 7u45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399944/warning-on-permissions-attribute-when-running-an-applet-with-jre-7u45/25895666#25895666)

you need to make a right manifest file. or you use the command line

`jar ufm jarfile.jar confmanifest.txt`

or you use maven.([Simpliest way to add an attribute to a jar Manifest in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645337/simpliest-way-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-jar-manifest-in-maven))

inside your manifest you'll edit permissions that its needed (socket, file, etc) and its codBase.(cross-origin and security purposes)

Then for running locally without a true CA signed certificate you'll need to edit your jvm java.policy file with `policytool`

JNLP is for signed jars/applets. But you can use this, its only an applet descriptor and you can excute it from everywhere, like you desktop.

With HTML5 you should use the `<object>` tag. I rather prefer deploy the applet via javascript and invoke applet methods with javascript methods.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

cy@.

Comment: well with policytool don't solve coz you can't deploy that as solution.