# What permissions are needed in the manifest file for an applet to communicate via Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, security, applet

We use Javascript to communicate between an applet and its hosting web page. We need to modify the applet to include the `permissions` attribute, and would like to know which value is needed for enabling Javascript communication for the applet. Can we use `sandbox` or do we need to use `all-permissions`?

Comment: Have you tried it (`sandbox`) before you asked?

Comment: Yes, we tried sandbox, but we're not sure if it works in all cases. And the applet security model has changed so much recently that we want to make sure we minimize the possibility of error for our users. Thanks.

Comment: The best way to minimize the possibility of errors for your users is to TEST on all versions of Java that you can get your hands on.  You need to do this anyway.  Indeed, you would need to do that anyway ... to validate whatever you were told here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet scripted by Java Script only needs the same permissions as the applet would without Java Script.

Having said that, any call from JS is not considered 'trusted' by the JVM.  So if a method that requires trust is **called from JS,** it will need to implement (in the code) use of [`doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged-java.security.PrivilegedAction-).

### More on [`AccessController`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html)

> The `AccessController` class is used for access control operations and decisions.
>
> More specifically, the `AccessController` class is used for three purposes:
>
> - to decide whether an access to a critical system resource is to be allowed or denied, based on the security policy currently in effect,
> - **to mark code as being "privileged", thus affecting subsequent access determinations,** and
> - to obtain a "snapshot" of the current calling context so access-control decisions from a different context can be made with respect to the saved context.

### More on [`PrivilegedAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html)

> A computation to be performed with privileges enabled. The computation is performed by invoking `AccessController.doPrivileged` on the `PrivilegedAction` object.  ..

---

Given the changing security regime, I would recommend wrapping **all code** that might **ever** be called from JS, into a `PrivilegedAction`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is you are looking for but for me it works if I deploy the applet with javascript: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

*sandbox* will work fine, but if you want to acess files or sockets you'll need to configure java.policy file:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep2.html

and grant permissions like  java.security.Permission or java.io.FilePermission

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399944/warning-on-permissions-attribute-when-running-an-applet-with-jre-7u45/25895666#25895666

Comment: well doing this is not deployable, cause client wont have permission, for that you'll need a true CA certificate