# java 6 applet blocked by java 7

Tags: java, applet, java-7, executable-jar, java-6

I have an applet that was coded back in 2011 with java 6 requirements. Due to the recent security updates, the applet is blocked by java and displays a grey screen.

I have updated the manifest file to include permissions, codebase, and Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase attributes. I have also updated libraries' manifest files and signed them with a certificate.

Lowering the Java security setting to medium and adding the site to 'exception site list' didn't help.

I have attached the log from java console. Some of the entries indicate that codebase and other attributes are missing from some libraries but that is not the case.

```
Java Plug-in 10.67.2.01
Using JRE version 1.7.0_67-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@e8f27e
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@19cfefb
security: Expected Main URL: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1409153789769
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409155180119 (we have 1409153789769)
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@5131c1ee: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar: read=332 full=60092
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@5131c1ee: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 1043 http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\24\48a1ac18-317f20b3.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Loading Deployment certificates from C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Loaded Deployment certificates from C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer TrustedPublisher certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Loading certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Internet Explorer ROOT certificate store
security: Loading Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Loaded Root CA certificates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Loaded blacklisted.certs file: C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\blacklisted.certs
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: EDA1BA32F297A9B90F294AE662E9FF31DC9C9DE88E1CB439C1CDF667EF15D53D
security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@5131c1ee: 3
security: Decision hash not matching ai: Appinfo:
type = 2
title = main.MainWindow
vendor = null
from = http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
security = 0
lapURL = http://***.***.***.***:81//main/MainApplet
appArgs = ##docbase:http://***.***.***.***:81/##Parameters:{height=716, __applet_relaunched=false, java_arguments=, width=1203, launchjnlp=, archive=Phase1.jar, code=main/MainApplet.class, embedded=, codebase=http://***.***.***.***:81/}
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
cache: Clean up the reference queue: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@5131c1ee: 2
security: User has granted the privileges to the code for this session only
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: EDA1BA32F297A9B90F294AE662E9FF31DC9C9DE88E1CB439C1CDF667EF15D53D
security: Decision time stored for ai: Appinfo:
type = 2
title = main.MainWindow
vendor = null
from = http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
security = 0
lapURL = http://***.***.***.***:81//main/MainApplet
appArgs = ##docbase:http://***.***.***.***:81/##Parameters:{height=716, __applet_relaunched=false, java_arguments=, width=1203, launchjnlp=, archive=Phase1.jar, code=main/MainApplet.class, embedded=, codebase=http://***.***.***.***:81/}
security: Grant socket perm for http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar : java.security.Permissions@13c3ba2 (
 ("java.net.SocketPermission" "***.***.***.***" "connect,accept,resolve")
)

security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.7.0_67
    requested: null
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: null
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.67
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.67
security: continue with running version
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.67
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.67
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 275095 us, pluginInit dt 7667257 us, TotalTime: 7942352 us
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153798241 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@9ecd0193: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar: read=85 full=7365
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@9ecd0193: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 1005 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\16\51720d90-6d25acb9.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 82C0F2C60A83887EA2D2E3190E9EC0F5F2C984F27C4540B95C6FFBBC8C18165A
security: Checking if certificate is in Internet Explorer DISALLOWED certificate store
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@5131c1ee: 3
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 82C0F2C60A83887EA2D2E3190E9EC0F5F2C984F27C4540B95C6FFBBC8C18165A
security: Decision cert hash not matching
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.11
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: User has granted the privileges to the code for this session only
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 82C0F2C60A83887EA2D2E3190E9EC0F5F2C984F27C4540B95C6FFBBC8C18165A
security: Decision time stored for ai: Appinfo:
type = 2
title = null
vendor = null
from = http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/lucene-1.4.3.jar
security = 0
lapURL = http://***.***.***.***:81//main/MainApplet
appArgs = ##docbase:http://***.***.***.***:81/##Parameters:{height=716, __applet_relaunched=false, java_arguments=, width=1203, launchjnlp=, archive=Phase1.jar, code=main/MainApplet.class, embedded=, codebase=http://***.***.***.***:81/}
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153802972 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@91fe9bce: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar: read=67 full=2010
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@91fe9bce: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 1005 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\40\613739e8-5821d88d.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse-extras.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153804229 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@1d10947c: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar: read=67 full=9365
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@1d10947c: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 1005 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\25\3a0538d9-2b9d5d4f.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/prefuse.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153806325 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@3479dd36: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar: read=319 full=29489
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jarcache: Clean up the reference queue: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar
cache: deregisterReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@5131c1ee: 2
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@3479dd36: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 1005 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\36\4cb69924-4f47653b.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/colt.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153806566 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@3e830523: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar: read=253 full=253
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@3e830523: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 1005 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\18\3fd1b552-228058ea.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153807190 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@26f6c715: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar: read=206 full=2349
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@26f6c715: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 6368 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\23\4fc3f817-68a5d2cf.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/imap.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153808155 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@591f1a79: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar: read=230 full=7166
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@591f1a79: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 13516 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\48\49bce370-4169465e.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mail.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153809079 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@bef7f57b: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar: read=230 full=4952
cache: Loading full manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jarcache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@bef7f57b: 2
cache: Reading Signers from 9969 http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar | C:\Users\*\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\36\403bf524-15b10719.idx
cache: Done readSigners(http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar)
security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/mailapi.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1409153809518 (we have 1409153789769)
network: Cache entry found [url: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar
cache: Resource http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar with proxy=HTTP @ web-proxy.atl.hp.com/16.114.29.150:8080
network: ResponseCode for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@7e288f44: 1
cache:  Read manifest for http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/pop3.jar: read=507 full=507
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Comment: POP3, IMAP and Lucene? A full featured mail client in an *Applet*?

Comment: yeah, its required by the project.

Comment: Was the cert issued by a CA? Is it expired?

Comment: Yeah, the log: security: Trust for: http://***.***.***.***:81/Phase1.jar has ended: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969 ... Wouldn't that be the start of the unix epoch? The date of the client system is maybe off.

Comment: originally I believe it was issued by CA but I'm self-signing the applet right now.

Comment: @owlstead its hosted on a server and using my computer as the client. My system date/time is current.

Answer (score 0):

I answer that here [Warning on Permissions attribute when running an applet with JRE 7u45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399944/warning-on-permissions-attribute-when-running-an-applet-with-jre-7u45/25895666#25895666)

run the java.policy tool to edit the policy file and it works. Find the right jre your applet is running.

```
 policytool
```

And how it works http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep2.html

Edit the *java.policy* file to grant your applet *socket-permissions*. You can grant all codBase leaving blank or putting your address like  `http://***.***.***.***:81/lib/`