# Codebase attribute in manifest mismatch when testing local

Tags: java, netbeans, manifest, java-web-start

As per Java 1.7u25 you should add the **Codebase** attribute to your manifest and I have done that.

But now I can't test it locally as the the attribute value does not match my local JNLP, generated by Netbeans, wich have no codebase value.

**What value should the manifest have for its Codebase and/or what do I have as codebase in my jnlp for it to work locally?**

Comment: You wrote : `But now I can test it locally` so where is the problem ?

Comment: Ah, stupid typo. I meant and have edited to "can't"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this:

1. **Use multiple codebase attributes:**

   You can supply multiple values to the `Codebase` attributes, thus allowing you to add local addresses as well.

   e.g: `Codebase: myproductiondomain.com localhost 127.0.0.1`
2. **Use Wildcards:**

   You can also use a wildcard attribute in the `Codebase` attribute, which can have multiple forms:

   - e.g. `Codebase: 127.0.0.1` (beware, that doesn't allow you to use `localhost`!!)
   - e.g. a much more lenient `Codebase: *`
3. **Build Changes:**

   But more likely, you should modify your build system to produce a test and a production version using different `Codebase` attributes to prevent abuse.

Everything you need is in [Preventing RIAs from being Repurposed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/no_redeploy.html):

Pay extra attention to that fun tidbit in the table of accepted wildcard saying, for the `127.0.0.1` entry:

> **Does not Match** [...] `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I've added an answer on how to automatically add those missing attributes as part of Netbeans build process.

It's a method that works with JavaFX, but it could give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19014303/2382937