# JAR manifest codebase mismatch

Tags: java, deployment, applet

I have an applet hosted  in dropbox, and a link in droppages. The applet is selfsigned. Follow the code

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Class-Path: lib/GammingImage.jar lib/SolomonKingdomResources.jar
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Codebase: ...(etc)
```

jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
  <information>
    <title>SolomonKingdom</title>
    <vendor>Usuario</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>SolomonKingdom</description>
    <description kind="short">SolomonKingdom</description>
 <offline-allowed/>
</information>
 <update check="background"/>
 <security>
  <all-permissions/>
 </security>
<resources>
    <j2se java-vm-args="-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy" version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="SolomonKingdom.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/GammingImage.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/SolomonKingdomResources.jar"/>
</resources>
<applet-desc height="768" main-class="solomonkingdom.loginScreen" name="SolomonKingdom" width="1024">
</applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Too I already did add the exceptions to Java Panel

```
http://mygame.droppages.com/
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78281142/launch.jnlp
```

And a lot more...

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest codebase mismatch for dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78281142/SolomonKingdom.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Someone can say what I need do to find where I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: 1) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78281142/launch.jnlp is a 404 error.  2) Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/). 3) At what URL can we visit the applet? 4) Note that putting things like `Codebase: ...(etc)` is extremely unhelpful.  We need a lot more details to sort this out.  Where is the HTML?  What is the code base? What is the location of the Jars?  ..

Answer (score 0):

With that error message, the most important part is the Codebase-property.
For a first try put
`Codebase: *`
in your manifest file.
For more details see  [codebase-attribute-in-manifest-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534312/codebase-attribute-in-manifest-mismatch-when-testing-local)