# topcoder java client blocked by java security

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm using `javaws ContestAppletProd.jnlp` to run the latest topcoder client on ubuntu 16.04.

java version is 
`java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)`.

I've added `http://www.topcoder.com` to the `exception site list` in java security control panel, but it doesn't work.

This is [the trace log file](https://gist.github.com/suiyuan2009/b847568bf9843cf1e33398a1acdd7e1c).

Comment: Check the manifest file for `Codebase`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516154/jar-manifest-codebase-mismatch