# How do I fix "missing Codebase, Permissions, and Application-Name manifest attribute" in my JNLP app?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

With the recent Java updates, many people are having trouble with their Java Web Start apps lacking `Codebase`, `Permissions`, and `Application-name` manifest attributes. Although there are resources out there to help you accomplish this, I couldn't find any **comprehensive** answers to this question, I so I felt a Q-and-A would be good. So, here's the question:

**My Java Web Start app displays the following warnings in the console:**

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://www.codebase.com/myApp/dist/myApp.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://www.codebase.com/myApp/dist/myApp.jar
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://www.codebase.com/myApp/dist/myApp.jar
```

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**(1)** First, you need to create a text file with all of the attributes you want to add. My text file looks like this:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: http://www.codebase.com/myApp/dist
Application-Name: My Application
```

I named it `addToManifest.txt`. Obviously, you'll need to change the parameters to match your application's needs.

**(2)** Next, you need to add this to the main .jar and all of the libraries as well. The command to do this is:

```
jar ufm dist\myApp.jar addToManifest.txt
```

of course `dist\myApp.jar` will need to point to whatever your main .jar is. You'll also need to do this for all of the libraries as well.

```
jar ufm dist\lib\jcommon-1.0.16.jar addToManifest.txt
jar ufm dist\lib\jfreechart-1.0.13.jar addToManifest.txt
jar ufm dist\lib\joda-time-2.2.jar addToManifest.txt
...
```

(Note: on Windows, I wrote a `.bat` file for this.)

Once you do this, the attributes should be written to the `.jar`s. You can open the .jars in a zip manager (like 7-Zip), extract the `MANIFEST.MF` file, open it in a text editor, and you should see the attributes listed.

**(3)** After adding the attributes, you need to resign your app. The command to do that is:

```
jarsigner dist\myApp.jar -keystore "C:\myApp\KEYSTORE.ks" alias -storepass password
```

You'll also need to do this for all of your libraries as well:

```
jarsigner dist\lib\jcommon-1.0.16.jar -keystore "C:\myApp\KEYSTORE.ks" alias -storepass password
jarsigner dist\lib\jfreechart-1.0.13.jar -keystore "C:\myApp\KEYSTORE.ks" alias -storepass password
jarsigner dist\lib\joda-time-2.2.jar -keystore "C:\myApp\KEYSTORE.ks" alias -storepass password
```

After that, your attributes should be added and your `.jar`s should be signed!

NOTE: You only need to sign/deploy your libraries once unless you are changing the library structure. i.e., if you are updating your app but the libraries have already had their manifests altered, signed properly, and deployed, you won't need to resign/deploy the libraries unless you are adding/removing libraries from your app.

<s>NOTE #2: The current version of Netbeans will add `Codebase` and `Permissions` manifest attributes to your **primary .jar only**, but not to your libraries. If you use Netbeans, you will receive a warning from the `jar` utility when you try to add a duplicate manifest attribute. There is a bug report in the queue to have this fixed https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234231.</s>

EDIT: The latest version of Netbeans (8.0) now adds all three (`Codebase`, `Permissions`, and `Application-Name`) to the manifest for you.

Comment: "Note: If the `Codebase` attribute does not specify a secure server, such as HTTPS, some risk exists that your code could be repurposed in Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attack schemes." See also *JAR File Manifest Attributes for Security*, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Could you advice on how to deal with the situation where Codebase is unknown, i.e. I need to have Codebase: * in the manifest, as application is deployed in many places. Is there any way to avoid warnings? Thanks.

Comment: @norbi771  Either package it specific for each deployment, or easier, package it for one place, then simply call that single deployment from all the other apps.

Comment: Is it possible to just enter the manifest with a zip manager and change it by hand? wouldn't it be simpler?

Comment: @Amos, no. That definitely wouldn't be simpler. _Especially_ if you need repackage/resign your .jars every time you release an update.

Comment: Don't forget to add a newline at the end of the file!

Comment: is this fixed in netbeans 8?? It would be great if you edit this great answer if it is solved :D

Comment: @johnny, this is done on the `.jar` files that contain your application which get deployed to the server. The program is launched via a `.jnlp` file which is downloaded to the client and executed.

Comment: Someone can help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959904/no-show-anymore-message-of-publisher-java Thanks!!

Comment: Note: My tests suggest that `Manifest!Application-Name` should be the same as `jnlp!information.title`

Answer (score 9):

Another way could be to handle it in your build script itself.

Step 1: Define a target to update

```
<target name="updateManifest">
    <manifest file="${file}" mode="update">         
        <attribute name="Trusted-Only" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions"/>
        <attribute name="Codebase" value="*"/>          
    </manifest>
</target>
```

Step 2: Call the update target and use the new manifest in jar

```
    <ant target="updateManifest">
        <property name="file" location="manifest.use" />
    </ant>

    <jar jarfile="${jar_name}.jar" manifest="manifest.use">
        <fileset dir="${dest}">
            <include name="File1" />                
        </fileset>
    </jar>
```

Comment: +1 -- it'd be even cooler if you provided the signjar task, as that needs to be (re)done as shown in step (3) of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659135/1168342

Answer (score 3):

If the error message looks like this:

```
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: server root/filename.jar
```

You can solve it this way:

1. Start `control panel`
2. Choose `Java Control Panel`
3. Select `Security` tab
4. At `Exception Site list` click on `Edit Site List` button
5. Click on `Add` button.
6. Type the server root (eg.:https://ibank.cib.hu), and press `OK`
7. Restart your browser/application.

[*Resource here.*](http://www.cib.hu/internetbank/hirek/index?id=f7e173)

Comment: This isn't really a solution. This is just a way to ignore the problem, not solve it. Shutting down the computer would be another way to ignore the problem without solving it.

Comment: @ryvantage this answer is for end-users.

Comment: I think this a good solution, usually you don't want all sites to be trusted.

Comment: @2astalavista, understood. Only problem is, the `Missing Application-Name` message is a warning that only appears in the console, not an error that will be manifest to the user unless they are clever enough to display the console. Further: we should be loath to suggest a work-around so that the end-user can rid themselves of a security warning just because they consider it a nuisance, even if they are powerless to fix the problem outright. I don't know what Oracle was hoping for with this warning, but it exists for a reason.

Comment: @ryvantage if it only appear in the console, I would not got involved in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Netbeans, set those attributes in your file nbproject/project.properties:

- manifest.custom.codebase
- manifest.custom.permissions
- manifest.application.name.attribute

The very last one is supported only by Netbeans >= 8.0 (see [here](http://hg.netbeans.org/jet-main/rev/a73f79ab9aaa)). The others should work even in Netbeans 7.2. I set jnlp.mixed.code to trusted_only too but maybe it isn't appropriate in your case. You can modify your file jnlp-impl.xml at your own risk if you can't switch to a more recent version of Netbeans.

atulsm's suggestion is better if you don't use Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Sample for adding `manifest` to jar and signing jars..

```
<target name="-post-compile">
        <jar destfile="${build.web.dir}/jars/app.jar" >
            <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}">
                <include name="com/sample/test/client/**/*.*"/>
                <include name="com/sample/test/share/**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Author" value="${user.name}"/>
                <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions"/>
                <attribute name="Codebase" value="http://localhost:8080/app/"/>
                <attribute name="Application-Name" value="App"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <signjar keystore="app.keystore"  storepass="test"  jar="${build.web.dir}/jars/app.jar" alias="tomcat" />


        <copyfiles files="${file.reference.javadatepicker.jar}" todir="${build.web.dir}/jars"/>


        <delete dir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/com/sample/app/client"/>
        <!--keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keystore app.keystore -keypass test -storepass test -validity 1960-->
        <signjar keystore="app.keystore"  storepass="test"  jar="${build.web.dir}/jars/javadatepicker.jar" alias="tomcat" />

    </target>
```