# RCP Web Start stops working with Java 7 update 45

Tags: java, eclipse, java-web-start, rcp, jnlp

After update JRE to 1.7 update45, my Eclipse(3.6) Web Start application can not be launched anymore. I try to add following security attributes in the manifest of jars to solve it.

- Permissions: all-permissions
- Codebase: *
- Application-Name: Application

But after I modify the manifest of Eclipse JAR(a signed JAR) and resigned using my own certificate, it pops up exception when start-up: **Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes**

My questions are:

1. When use java 1.7_45, is it mandatory to add these security attributes to manifest of   all application JARS(including Eclipse JARS) ?
2. If it's mandtory, how can I add these attributes for Eclipse JARS? The Eclipse JARS are already been signed, we cannot modify the manifest easily.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What was the actual problem, any errors when you start your application? Post them! Which security changes should be applied? Are you doing some cryptography? Do you mean the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add Codebase, Permissions, and Application-Name to my JNLP app manifest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-add-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-to-my-jnlp-app-manifest)

Comment: My application is RCP Web Start Application, I want to add Codebase, Permission and Application-Name to Eclipse JARS(already signed with Eclipse certificate), how can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

**Your question first:**

1. If you are going to self-sign, **you should create your own keystore and tell Eclipse to use that to sign your .jars**. That way you can reuse that same keystore to resign your .jars when you add the necessary manifest attributes. Don't tell Eclipse to self-sign using a generated keystore. About half-way down [this page](http://www.dallaway.com/acad/webstart/) has instructions on how to create your own keystore (NOTE: this should only serve as a temporary fix, you should get away from self-signed apps. Read the bottom of this post).
2. I could be wrong, but if you are adding your manifest attributes via a text editor, that will not work. I am not sure **why**, but I tried to add them via a text editor and it did not work. You should place what you need to add in a text file and add the manifest attributes via the command `jar ufm dist\myApp.jar addToManifest.txt` in the console.

**Not your question, but important:**

Self-signed keys are deprecated as of 7u25. If you work for a business or you have clients who use software, then I'd tell them you need a signed certificate from a [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). Even a small business should be able to afford the small amount it costs for a certificate. And it's very worth it if you are a contractor (like me) with multiple clients. **In fact,** it will be mandatory in the future. So, bite the bullet.

EDIT: for more information about how to add manifest attributes and re-sign, visit this thread: [How do I fix "missing Codebase, Permissions, and Application-Name manifest attribute" in my JNLP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-add-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-to-my-jnlp-app-manifest). You'll need a non-Eclipse-generated keystore, though.