# Java 7 web start issue with manifest file

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

I have upgraded to java 7 and unable to start Swing application via Java web start. It says 3 manifest attributes are missing: "Codebase", "Permissions" and "Application-name".

I added those missing attributes to manifest file while creating a .jar and signed them. I can see finally those attributes in the jar. But while launching Swing GUI from web start it says same error 3 manifest attributes are missing.

Comment: The proper way to add the manifest attributes and sign them can be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659135/963076

Answer (score 1):

You need to update those items in the JNLP not the jar since you are launching this via webstart.

Example from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase=
"http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo" 
    href="dynamictree_webstart.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Dynamic Tree Demo</title>
        <vendor>Dynamic Team</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="DynamicTreeDemo.jar"
            main="true" />

    </resources>
    <application-desc
         name="Dynamic Tree Demo Application"
         main-class=
           "webstartComponentArch.DynamicTreeApplication"
         width="300"
         height="300">
     </application-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

For permissions you possibly need the security tag, here is a writeup about that tag from: http://lopica.sourceforge.net/ref.html#security

> By default every application runs in a restricted execution
>   environment (aka sandbox). If an app runs in a secure sandbox, it must
>   follow these restrictions:
>
> No access to local disk. All your jars must be downloaded from the
>   same host. Note, however, that you can download extensions and JREs
>   from any host as long as they are signed and trusted. Network
>   connections are allowed only to host from which your jars were
>   downloaded. ("Phone home restriction.") No security manager can be
>   installed. No native libraries (not even in extensions). Limited
>   access to system properties. (The application has read/write access to
>   all system properties defined in the jnlp file, as well as read-only
>   access to the same set of properties as applets (see System Properties
>   Available for Unsigned Apps for a complete list).) If you specify
>   all-permissions, the app can do whatever it wants and has full access
>   to the user's machine and local network.
>
> Contents
>
> all-permissions?, j2ee-application-client-permissions?

```
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by you clearly says update jar am not sure why you are saying jnlp file. JNLP file is in place and has securty tag