# java web start application unable to launch on java7u45

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp

After the upgrade to java7u45 from java7u21 , there have been a lot of security related changes done.

So first there were warnings related to missing attributes in manifest files. Fixed it by following previously provided [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-fix-missing-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-manifest-attri) .

```
Permissions: all-permissions  
Codebase: *  
Application-Name: My Name
```

Added the attributes to the MANIFEST file and re-signed them all.
Now when I launch the application using my jnlp file, it gives following error on this particular jar

```
Error: Unable to load resource 
http://<path>/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_<version>.jar
java.io.IOException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Verified the manifest file for this jar for missing attributes and signed it again. But same error .

Any pointers ?

Comment: Is this .jar a library file or the main application .jar?

Comment: Sorry for soooo much delayed response. This .jar is eclipse library file.

Comment: @ryvantage - I figured it out. This `org.eclipse*.jar` and some other eclipse jar files have their own Signature Files (ECLIPSEF.SF) in the META-INF/ directory. Since this extra SF file still has the **SHA-DIGEST of the previous MANIFEST main attributes(which were now changed)** , the plugin was failing to load. I removed these and other signature files from all the plugins and re-signed them with my own certificate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `org.eclipse*.jar` and some other eclipse jar files have their own Signature Files **(ECLIPSEF.SF)** in the **META-INF/** directory.

Since this extra SF file still has the **SHA-DIGEST of the previous MANIFEST main attributes(which were now changed)** , the plugin is failing to load.

Remove these and other signature files from all the plugins and re-sign them. :-)