# Java Web Start Security warning JNLP. Bug in JWS? 7u51

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp

We are using java web start to launch a GUI java program. We sign all the jars including third party jars. We also added the Permissions: all-permissions attribute to the manifest of all our jars, but not to the third party jars.

In java 7u51 we still get the warning that 'this application will be blocked'.

I have tried looking through the java console logs after starting web start with -verbose but didn't see anything that helped me resolve this.

[image: Warning dialog]

Comment: I deleted my answer but I wanted to address your last comment: "We are signing the jars properly. The certificate has not expired. This error came up for us with 7u45. We added the permissions: all-permissions attribute to all our manifest's which made the dialog not appear (this is oracles suggested 'fix'). Then with 7u51, we get the dialog again" Well, the dialog says that your .jar file does not contain the `Permissions` attribute. So, I would re-check to make sure your main .jar and library .jars contain the attribute and that it matches your .jnlp file.

Comment: There's the problem: "We also added the Permissions: all-permissions attribute to the manifest of all our jars, but not to the third party jars." You need to add the attribute to your third-party libraries as well. You threw me off when you said "all of our .jars." But yes, add the attribute to your third-party .jars.

Comment: As far as I can tell it shouldn't be required to add this attribute to any jar other than the main jar. I cannot find any definitive answer to this since the documentation is so bad. It is unreasonable to have to modify third party jars. We actually tried this just to rule this out and adding the attribute to EVERY SINGLE JAR we serve up. Still got this dialog. Also, some jars you simply CANNOT modify the manifest. Namely Bouncy Castle jars since they require that they remain signed by the original signer. This leads me to believe its a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027821

Comment: I'm confused. On one hand, you said you added the attribute to every single jar, yet on the other hand you said some .jars cannot be modified?? By cannot did you mean cannot by law? If that is what you're saying, I totally agree. If you read my answer to a similar SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759765/java-7-manifest-security-changes/20772852#20772852 you'll see that I am totally with you. Oracle has put developers in a precarious position by requiring them to modify 3rd-party libraries. Of course, if you use an IDE to build your app, you are modifying them anyways.

Comment: I'm on your side here. I think it's ridiculous that they require you to change the library .jars, but (and I'm not going to argue this with you) it is the only way to get rid of this security warning.

Comment: Note: uploading a new version of your app does not always force the download of the new libraries. So, although you may have modified the 3rd party .jars to test what I'm saying, your app might be loading cached .jars.

Comment: Caching is not an issue here, we clear the cache between subsequent tests and verify the new jars are being download. The only modification we do is sign all third party jars, we don't do any other modification. Adding an attribute to the manifest effectively renders any existing signature invalid. We use bouncy castle as a security provider and if we modify the manifest bouncy castle refuses to work. "if you use an IDE.. you are modifying them anyways". What you are referring to here? Do you have any documentation that says the permissions attribute is required in all jars loaded w/web start?

Comment: Also, as I said before, just to test this we added the permissions attribute to every single jar (not for production, simply for testing this issue) and we still got the dialog. If you have any documentation that you know of, from oracle would be nice, to support the claim that we must modify every single jar we serve, including third party jars, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Well, I suppose I don't have any documentation from Oracle. What I do have, however, is console warnings displayed at runtime should your main .jar or any library .jars omit the attributes. So, if Oracle didn't expect you to put the attributes in the manifest, why warn you when you don't? Mayhap, could be a bug as well?

Comment: Ill have to do some more testing and see If I can figure out why this keeps coming up. Ill post anything if I figure something out.

Comment: Make sure your console is visible during your testing. Lots of useful information in there when you run JWS apps.

Comment: I added a few more attributes to our manifests. I added 'Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *', 'Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *', 'Codebase: *'. Looking at the jws log (using -verbose) this removes all security warnings about missing attributes, but unfortunately we still get this security warning. I also tried with 7u60 b11to see if Oracle fixed this but we still get this error. I'm  giving up for now.

Comment: Have you tried with Java 8, released last week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was fixed with 7u55 update.

[7u55 Bug fixes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u55-bugfixes-2180733.html):

JDK-8031579 deploy webstart Spurious Missing Manifest Permissions Attribute Warning When Launching versioned Java Web Start app