# Application-Name or Applet-Name?

Tags: java, deployment, applet, manifest.mf

If I got it right, the txt file that I should add to the manifest file has to look something like this: (using this tutorial:[How do I fix "missing Codebase, Permissions, and Application-Name manifest attribute" in my JNLP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-fix-missing-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-manifest-attri))

```
Permissions: kind of permission
Codebase: the path to my project files
Application-Name: my applet's name
```

I understood why the first two lines are needed, but I didn't understand the third one and I couldn't find it on google, what is it used for? if it doesn't have to be any file's name, and it is not seen by the end user what is it good for?
and something else I'm not sure about, if I'm making an applet, should it be "Applet-Name" instead of "Application-Name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the linked question, it is the `title` element of the `information` section.  So for the JNLP shown at [Structure of the JNLP File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html) it would be `Dynamic Tree Demo`.

> ..if I'm making an applet, should it be "Applet-Name" instead of "Application-Name"?

I doubt it.  Note that one Jar might contain an hybrid application/applet - one that can be deployed either way.  They would have the same title, so it unnecessary to distinguish between the two (in the `title` element *or* the manifest).