# Javaws application getting permission warning while MANIFEST has the Permissions Attribute

Tags: java, permissions, manifest, java-web-start

I am running my application through javaws and I am getting the following message although I have the following line in my jar MANIFEST.MF.

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

> This application will be blocked in a future Java security update because the JAR file manifest does not contain the Permissions attribute. Please contact the Publisher for more information.
> <kbd>More Information</kbd>

What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my Manifest file content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: * 
Application-Name: XYZ 
Permissions: all-permissions 
Created-By: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) 
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: * 
Main-Class: com.xyz.Main Codebase: * 

Name: com/xyz/print/Table.class 
SHA1-Digest: VTfZjW9GqKB39EmlNA= 

Name: common Implementation-Vendor: XYZ 
Implementation-Title: client 
Implementation-Version: 1391524251884 
Specification-Vendor: XYZ 
Built-By: kuka 
Specification-Title: 
Client Specification-Version: 

Name: com/xyz/print/Element$1.class 
SHA1-Digest: ucbptZrxyzfaalv6FYw=
```

Comment: Have you opened the Jar to check the manifest that you made is actually the one in the Jar?  Does your manifest end in an entirely blank line?  What is the total content of the manifest (is the `Permissions` line last)? ..

Comment: Do you have all-permissions also set in your JNLP file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have all-permissions in the JNLP file, I have opened the jar and found that the manifest file there contains the Permissions attribute in the first "paragraph", and the file has 2 empty lines at the end. What else could it be?

Comment: Make sure all your library .jars are signed as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-fix-missing-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-manifest-attri

Comment: Tip: Add @ryvantage (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.  2) Post the content of the JNLP.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in 1.7.0_45 there was a case where webstart would report this message when it was actually hitting a problem with something unrelated: the message was just generic and confusing, and probably misfired as part of the changes in that version. Which version are you running on btw?

Comment: @haylem I am running java 1.7.0_51.

Comment: @ryvantage Here is the content of the manifest file:@ryvantage Here is the content of the

Comment: @ryvantage Sorry, again:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: XYZ
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Main-Class: com.xyz.Main
Codebase: *

Name: com/xyz/gui/Command$9.class
SHA1-Digest: RssmI/y7xuQlM94/E=

Name: common
Implementation-Vendor: XYZ
Implementation-Title: client
Implementation-Version: 1391524251884
Specification-Vendor: XYZ
Built-By: kuka
Specification-Title: Client
Specification-Version: 

Name: com/xyz/print/Element$1.class
SHA1-Digest: ucbptZv+v2Plv6FYw=

Comment: @ryvantage `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: XYZ
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_24 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Main-Class: com.xyz.Main
Codebase: *

Name: com/xyz/print/Table.class
SHA1-Digest: VTfZjW9GqKB39EmlNA=

Name: common
Implementation-Vendor: XYZ
Implementation-Title: client
Implementation-Version: 1391524251884
Specification-Vendor: XYZ
Built-By: kuka
Specification-Title: Client
Specification-Version: 

Name: com/xyz/print/Element$1.class
SHA1-Digest: ucbptZrxyzfaalv6FYw=`

Comment: 1) Instead of posting all of that in a comment, make an edit to your OP and paste it as code so we can read it. 2) Having said that, my suggestion to you was to verify that all of your library .jars are repackaged as well as your main .jar. Did you do that?

Comment: @ryvantage Sorry about that lousy comment. Yes all the library jars manifest files have the all permissions and code base lines added

Comment: My experiences today suggest that if a jar file is blocked for a user because it doesn't satisfy the security policy, it may remain blocked for that user even after it has been updated to correct the problem.  Try testing with a different user account, or wipe the user profile for your test account.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for the comment, but what do you mean by user here?

Comment: The operating system account that the web browser is running in.

Comment: How many jar files are there in your application? When starting an applet, I found that java checks the **first** jar on the class path for the Permissions attribute, not the one that your applet class resides in.