# Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar

Tags: nullpointerexception, permissions, applet

I am trying to run an applet in html, but keep getting this NullPointerException.

Below is the stacktrace,

```
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/User/workspace/SearchAlgorithms/bin/Main.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Fri Apr 24 15:09:46 IST 2015,length=10095
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: file:/C:/Users/User/workspace/SearchAlgorithms/bin/Main.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dataProduct.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main.init(Main.java:39)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dataLocation.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main.init(Main.java:45)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Java Plug-in 10.79.2.15
Using JRE version 1.7.0_79-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\User
```

---

Things that I have tried:

1. Signing the jar file
2. Including the accesscontrol.dopriviledge,

   ```
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new PrivilegedExceptionAction<FileInputStream>() {
            public FileInputStream run() throws FileNotFoundException {
                return new FileInputStream("someFile");
            }
        });
    } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
        // e.getException() should be an instance of FileNotFoundException,
        // as only "checked" exceptions will be "wrapped" in a
        // PrivilegedActionException.
        throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getException();
    }
   ```

The applet runs perfectly on the applet viewer. But embedding in html, gives the NullPointerException.

Please Help.

Comment: What `NullPointerException`???   You have shown us a `FileNotFoundException` stacktrace

Comment: Have you tried adding a permissions attribute to the manifest?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your comment. It says a nullpointexception on the popupwindow when running the html. Could you please guide me with the permissions attribute to the manifest.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659134/how-do-i-fix-missing-codebase-permissions-and-application-name-manifest-attri