# When updating items or drag and drop TableColumns in TableView in JavaFX 8 the TableView breaks

Tags: css, javafx-2, tableview, javafx-8

I created my application with JavaFX 2.1 and recently upgraded to JDK 8 with JavaFX 8.

When I change the value of a ComboBox, the TableView breaks, but if I select something in the  table, it's ok.

Netbeans displays:

> javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue WARNING: Could not resolve
>   '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for
>   '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.list-cell' in stylesheet
>   jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
>
> javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue WARNING: Could not resolve
>   '-fx-selection-bar' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color'
>   from rule
>   '*.combo-box-popup>*.list-view>*.virtual-flow>*.clipped-container>*.sheet>*.list-cell:hover:filled:selected'
>   in stylesheet
>   jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss

Is there a problem with new JavaFX 8 and the old CSS?

Also Netbeans shows

> Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing. Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.

Comment: Your NetBeans codebase question is a duplicate of [Missing Codebase manifest attribute for:xxx.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275384/missing-codebase-manifest-attribute-forxxx-jar).  In general, try to ask one question per question, otherwise the Q&A gets much to confusing for others.  Your original question on CSS compatibility is a reasonable one and still stands of course.  I'd advise including in your question any custom CSS file you may be using and also provide more comprehensive reproduction instructions.

Comment: I do not have any custom CSS file in my application.For the warning about manifest I thought it could have some connection with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this jira issue : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31869 which desrcibes the problem above.