# Error when building javafx application in Netbean (manifest.custom.codebase property)

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Whenever I try to build my project in Netbeans I get the following errors:

```
ant -f /Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L jfx-build
init:
Deleting: /Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/build/built-jar.properties
compile:
Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under /Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/dist/lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
/Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3438: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1465: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3092: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/user/Documents/NETBEANS/MICO_L/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:1636: All filesets are empty.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

What cuase this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Which `Netbeans` version are you using?

Comment: There was a workaround for this bug in [Netbeans 7.x](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19014303/1759128). You can check if it works for you as well.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha okay so I copy the code to my build.xml and and manifest.custom.codebase to the manifest.mf. Can I just use the example and set it to localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old but all I had to do was rebuild the project. Something got messed up in the netbeans build files or something. I hope this helps.